# i faced this problem while running my app help would be appreciated

Tags: flutter, dart

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.Gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
> Android resource linking failed
> ERROR:C:\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_app\i_am_rich\build\app\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:17: AAPT: error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher (aka com.example.i_am_rich:mipmap/ic_launcher) not found.

Comment: read the last line there it have clearly written  error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher (aka com.example.i_am_rich:mipmap/ic_launcher) not found.

Comment: have you done any changes in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

try to delete or comment this mete tag in your app/AndroidManifest.xml

```html
 <meta-data
    android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
    android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
    />
```